# The product of two numbers that can be written as the sum of two squares

Tags: number-theory

Prove that if n is the product of two numbers that can be written as the sum of two squares then n can be written as the sum of two squares.

Comment: Ready formula you should look there.  http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/153603/diophantine-equation-a2b2-c2d2/736164#736164

Answer (score 4):

See the [Brahmagupta–Fibonacci identity](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Brahmagupta%E2%80%93Fibonacci_identity).

Or consider the formula for the product of two complex numbers, and take the moduli.

Answer (score 0):

A number can be written as the sum of two squares iff each of its prime divisors of the form $p = 4k + 3$ occurs to an even power. So if $n = ab$ and $a$ and $b$ have this property, so will their product.

See [Integer as sum of Two Squares](https://proofwiki.org/wiki/Integer_as_Sum_of_Two_Squares)

Comment: This is quite an heavy machinery for such a question ! ;)