# In how many ways can a number be expressed as a sum of squares of two natural numbers?

Tags: elementary-number-theory, sums-of-squares

In how many ways can $145^2$ be expressed as sum of two squares?

---

I tried solving it by finding out the Pythagoren triplets. $145= m^2+n^2 = 12^2+1^2$ & $9^2+8^2$ so triplet is $(145, m^2-n^2 , 2mn) = (145,143,24)=29*(5,4,3)$ & $(145,17,144)$ & one will come from $29$.. i.e $5*(29,21,20)$ total triplets 4. $(145,143,24)$ , $(145,17,144)$ , $(145,116,87)$ & $(145 , 105,100)$. Is there any easier way of doing this?

Comment: What have you tried? If you tell us this then we will be better able to help you. And it helps us feel that we are not just doing your homework for you.

Comment: I tried solving it by finding out the pythagoras triplets.145= m²+n² = 12²+1²   & 9²+8²  
so triplet is   (145, m²-n² , 2mn)  = (145,143,24) & (145,17,144)
29*(5,4,3)  & one will come from 29..     i.e 5*(29,21,20)
total triplets 4.
(145,143,24) , (145,17,144) , (145,116,87) & (145 , 105,100).Is there any easier way of doing this?

Comment: The formula for this equation you can see there.  http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/153603/diophantine-equation-a2b2-c2d2/736164#736164