# four different integers exist, what is the least product value?

Tags: analysis, number-theory, elementary-number-theory, contest-math, diophantine-equations

Four different positive integers $a, b, c, d$ are such that $a^2 + b^2 = c^2 + d^2$.
What is the smallest possible value of $abcd$?

$$a^2 - c^2 = d^2 - b^2$$

$$(a-c)(a+c) = (d-b)(d+b)$$

$$(a-c)(a+c) - (d-b)(d+b) = 0$$

So there is one pair I see:

$$a -c = d - b, a + c = d + b$$

Suppose WLOG, $a > b > c > d > 0$

But that doesnt strike anything.

Comment: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/153603/diophantine-equation-a2b2-c2d2/736164#736164

Comment: Find an example. To be represented as the sum of two squares in at least two essentially different ways, the number has to be a product $xy$ where $x$ and $y$ are sums of squares. Fool around until you find a candidate, then argue you have managed to get the least possible $abcd$.  The argument will be algebra-light.

Comment: @AndréNicolas, well obviously, one of them is one, so let $a = 2$. Let $c = 1$, RHS $= 3$. But trial and error seems hard for $b, d$.?

Comment: If WLOG $a > b > c > d > 0$, wouldn't that guarantee the strict inequality $a^2+b^2>c^2+d^2$?

Comment: You should have stopped at your second equation: $(a-c)(a+c)=(d-b)(d+b)$. (Hint: $1 \times 15 = 3 \times 5$.)

Comment: There's this one http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1117884/four-different-positive-integers-a-b-c-and-d-are-such-that-a2-b2-c2?rq=1

Comment: The smallest number that can be expressed as the sum of two different squares in two different ways is $65=1^2+8^2=4^2+7^2$. That gives product $(1)(8)(4)(7)$. Now showing you can't beat that is not entirely pleasant.