# If $a^2+ab+b^2=c^2+cd+d^2$ then $a+b+c+d$ is not prime.

Tags: elementary-number-theory, quadratics

Let $a,b,c,d$ be positive integers such that $a^2+ab+b^2=c^2+cd+d^2$. Show that $a+b+c+d$ is not prime.

My proof looks like this:

$(a+b)^2 - ab=(c+d)^2-cd$

$(a+b)^2 - (c+d)^2=ab-cd$

$(a+b+c+d)(a+b-c-d)=ab-cd$

$a+b+c+d=\frac{ab-cd}{a+b-c-d}$

I'd like to have $a+b+c+d$ as product (of integers) not quotient

Comment: *What* are you trying to prove?

Comment: that $a+b+c+d$ is a complex number, do I have to include $i$ in my proof ?

Comment: Real numbers are usually included when you say "complex". Perhaps you mean "non-real"?

Comment: Also, what exactly do you know in advance about the numbers $a,b,c,d$? This result: _"For $a,b,c,d$ positive integers, $a+b+c+d$ is not real"_ is obviously absurd. What did I get wrong?

Comment: @MartinR I think he's trying to prove the fact that if $n$ has the binary quadratic form representation $n = a^2+ab+b^2$ for $a,b \in \mathbb{Z}^{+}$, then such representation is unique :-)

Comment: positive integers are real numbers, $i$ is not right?  $a + bi$ I red this syntax of complex number on wiki and got confused

Comment: I think OP means composite number.

Comment: yes exactly sorry guys im new to these math terms

Comment: Either way, this isn't enough to prove the result - you have shown that $a+b+c+d$ is a quotient of two integers, while you have to show it's a product of two.

Answer (score 1):

It is necessary to use the formula.   [Diophantine equation $a^2+b^2=c^2+d^2$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/153603/diophantine-equation-a2b2-c2d2/740488#740488)

For example this.

You can write a similar equation and solutions:  $$a^2+ac+c^2=x^2+xy+y^2$$

Solutions have the form:  $$a=q^2+k^2-p^2+kq$$

$$c=q^2+k^2+2p^2+kq-3pk-3pq$$  $$x=q^2-2k^2-p^2+3pk-2qk$$  $$y=k^2-2q^2-p^2+3pq-2qk$$

This means that:

$$a+c+x+y=q^2+k^2-p^2-2qk=(q-k-p)(q-k+p)$$

Easy number can always choose.

$$(q-k-p)(q-k+p)=1*19$$

Then for example: it turns out one of the numbers is negative.  If we change the signs. $x=-x$ ; $y=-y$ . You get a multiple of 3 and the square. So simple number can be when $q=p-k+1$

This means that at least one number must be again negative.

Comment: wait; how did you get to that $(q−k−p)(q−k+p)=1∗19$ and how do I get that multiple of 3 how does it exactly look like? I don't see it

Comment: @II   $$a+c-x-y=3(q+k-p)^2$$