# The set of differences of square rationals

Tags: elementary-number-theory, diophantine-equations

At first, we observe that $A:=\{ p^2-m^2 : p,m\in \Bbb{Z}\}=\mathbb{Z}\setminus (4\mathbb{Z}+2)$ (because an integer $a$ can be written
as the form $a=p^2-m^2$ if and only if $a\neq 4k+2$, for every integer $k$) and so $A^c=4\mathbb{Z}+2$. Hence, $B:=\left\{ p^2-m^2 : p,m\in \Bbb{Z}\setminus \{0\}\right\}=A\setminus \left\{\pm k^2: k\in \Bbb{Z} \mbox{ and } k^2\neq s^2-t^2, \mbox{ for all } s,t\in \Bbb{Z}\right \}$

Now, put 
$$
D:=\left\{ \frac{p^2}{q^2}-\frac{m^2}{n^2}: p,q,m,n\in \Bbb{Z}\setminus \{0\} \text{ and} \gcd(p,q)=
\gcd(m,n) =1\right\}
$$
We would like to **determine this set and its complement $D^c$ in $\Bbb{Q}$** exactly.

It is clear that $B\subseteq D$. Is it true that $D\neq \Bbb{Q}$?

Comment: You don't need the gcd conditions in your definition of $D$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We have $4m = (m+1)^2-(m-1)^2$ for all $m \in \mathbb Z$. Therefore,
$$
\frac{a}{b}
=
\frac{4ab}{4b^2}
=
\frac{(ab+1)^2-(ab-1)^2}{(2b)^2}
=
\left(\frac{a b + 1}{2 b}\right)^2 - \left(\frac{a b - 1}{2 b}\right)^2
$$
When $ab=\pm 1$, one of the terms is zero. In this case, $\frac{a}{b}=\pm1$ and we can use
$$
1 = \left(\frac{5}{3}\right)^2 - \left(\frac{4}{3}\right)^2,
\quad
-1 = \left(\frac{4}{3}\right)^2 - \left(\frac{5}{3}\right)^2
$$
Thus, all rationals are the difference of two nonzero rational squares.

Comment: See https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1445058/which-rationals-can-be-written-as-the-sum-of-two-rational-squares for sum of two rational squares.

Answer (score 8):

If I understood you correctly, $D=\mathbb Q$ since
$$
\left(\frac{a b + 1}{2 b}\right)^2 - \left(\frac{a b - 1}{2 b}\right)^2 = \frac{a}{b}
$$

Comment: Thanks for your answer. What about the cases $ab=\pm 1$?

Comment: Of course, there are some mistakes in my explanations, now I correct them.

Answer (score 2):

The non degenerate quadratic form $X^2-Y^2$ obviously represents $0$ in $\mathbf Q$, i.e. the equation $x^2-y^2=0$ admits solutions $(x,y)\neq (0,0)$. But *a non degenerate quadratic form* $q(X)= \sum a_{ij}X_iX_j$ *in* $n$ *variables with rational coefficients which represents* $0$ *represents all rationals*. Indeed, $q(tX+Y)= t^2Q(X)+tb(X,Y)+f(Y)$, where $b(X,Y)$ is the bilinear form associated to the quadratic form $q(X)$. If $q(x)=0$ for a certain $x\neq (0,...,0)$, the non degeneracy of $q$ implies the existence of $y\in {\mathbf Q}^n$ s.t. $b(x,y)\neq 0$, so that $q(tx+y)$ is a non constant linear function of $t$ which takes all values in $\mathbf Q$ when $t$ runs through $\mathbf Q$. Note that the main property remains valid over any field of characteristic $\neq 0$.