# Prove that there are no rational numbers $x$ and $y$ such that $x^2+y^2=1002$

Tags: abstract-algebra, proof-writing

Prove that there are no rational numbers $x$ and $y$ such that $x^2+y^2=1002$.

Hello,

I am completely new to proofs and am having a hard time with this one. Can someone help me with it?

I figured we go with proof by contradiction and assume x and y are rational thus,

$$
x = \frac{p}{q} , \ y = \frac{s}{t},  \text{where} \ p,q,s,t \in \ Z \ \text{and} \ q , t\neq \ 0  ;
$$

But where should I go from there? Should I substitute that to $x^2+y^2=1002$ to get

$$
\left(\frac{p}{q}\right)^2 + \left(\frac{s}{t}\right)^2 = 1002
$$

to then simplify? Any advice is appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: See https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1445058/which-rationals-can-be-written-as-the-sum-of-two-rational-squares

Comment: $1002$ is divisible by $3$ but it isn't divisible by $9$.