# If $k(a^2+mb^2) = c^2+md^2$, what can be said about the form of $k$?

Tags: elementary-number-theory, divisibility, pell-type-equations

Let $k,a,b,c,$ and $d$ be integers, and let $m \ge 2$ be a non-square integer, such that
$$
k(a^2+mb^2) = c^2+md^2.
$$

**QUESTIONS:**

1. What can be said about the form of $k$ with no further restrictions?
2. What can be said about the form of $k$ when $m$ has further restrictions (*e.g.,* $m$ is a prime $p$ of a given form)?
3. **In particular:** Under what conditions is it guaranteed that $k=u^2+mv^2$ for some integers $u$ and $v$?

Comment: The formula in General as follows.   http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1127654/parametrization-of-solutions-of-diophantine-equation  Next, it is necessary to consider the equivalent form and find out the required coefficients.

Comment: Can we say $k $ is a square?

Comment: @N.S.JOHN: If that's one of the restrictions added, that's fine — but please make that explicit.

Comment: @N.S.JOHN If  $k$  square. Then, for any  $m$  the solution is always there.

Comment: For $m =1,2,3$ and $5$, point 3 is satisfied. I think a general solution has been given by Gauss using Quadratic Forms in his book "Disquisitiones Arithmeticae".

Comment: @KierenMacMillan [Releated](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1792782/factors-of-the-numbers-of-the-form-a2nb2)

Comment: @IshanSingh Would you mind writing a solution to this question and [my related question](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1792782/factors-of-the-numbers-of-the-form-a2nb2)? Thanks.