# Existence of solutions of Diophantine equations

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory

One of the problems in the book, I am quite confused to show this in a general way. How could I show that $x^2+y^2 = 3(u^2+v^2)$ has no nontrivial integral solutions?

It seems like these problems have a general way to show there are solutions or no solutions to them, and I can not do this yet as I just started to learn about Diophantine equations. Helping me understand the way to solve these problems would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1127654/parametrization-of-solutions-of-diophantine-equation

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no *general* way.

Rather, there is a *variety* of known methods and tricks which apply to various types of diophantine equations, and which give you a set of potential strategies. Experience and pattern matching provides the intuition as to which methods are likely to be useful for a given diophantine equation.

For the given equation, as shown below, analyzing it mod $3$ allows a key reduction . . .

Suppose there is a solution $(x,y,u,v)$ such that $x,y,u,v$ are integers, not all zero.

Of all such solutions, choose one such that $x^2 + y^2$ is least.

Since $x,y,u,v$ are not all zero, it follows that $x^2 + y^2$ is a positive integer.

Note that squares are congruent to $0$ or $1$ mod $3$.
\begin{align*}
\text{Then}\;\;&x^2 + y^2 = 3(u^2+v^2)\\[4pt]
\implies\;&3|(x^2 + y^2)\\[4pt]
\implies\;&x^2 + y^2 \equiv 0\;(\text{mod}\;3)\\[4pt]
\implies\;&x^2 \equiv 0\;(\text{mod}\;3)\;\;\text{and}\;\;y^2 \equiv 0\;(\text{mod}\;3)\\[4pt]
\implies\;&3|x\;\,\text{and}\;\,3|y\\[4pt]
\implies\;&9|x^2\;\,\text{and}\;\,9|y^2\\[4pt]
\implies\;&9|(x^2 + y^2)\\[4pt]
\implies\;&9|\bigl(3(u^2 + v^2)\bigr)\\[4pt]
\implies\;&3|(u^2 + v^2)\\[4pt]
\implies\;&u^2 + v^2 \equiv 0\;(\text{mod}\;3)\\[4pt]
\implies\;&u^2 \equiv 0\;(\text{mod}\;3)\;\;\text{and}\;\;v^2 \equiv 0\;(\text{mod}\;3)\\[4pt]
\implies\;&3|u\;\,\text{and}\;\,3|v\\[4pt]
\end{align*}
Hence we can write
$$
\begin{cases}
x = 3x_1
\qquad\;\;\;\;
\\[4pt]
y = 3y_1\\[4pt]
u = 3u_1\\[4pt]
v = 3v_1\\
\end{cases}
$$
for some integers $x_1,y_1,u_1,v_1$.

But then
\begin{align*}
&x^2 + y^2 = 3(u^2 + v^2)\\[4pt]
\implies\;&(3x_1)^2 + (3y_1)^2 = 3((3u_1)^2 + (3v_1)^2)\\[4pt]
\implies\;&x_1^2 + y_1^2 = 3(u_1^2 + v_1^2)\\[4pt]
\end{align*}
so we have a solution $(x_1,y_1,u_1,v_1)$ with
$$x_1^2 + y_1^2 < x^2 + y^2$$
contrary to the choice of $(x,y,u,v)$.

It follows that the given equation has no nontrivial integer solutions.

Comment: Thank you, I will try to understand the logic behind this

Comment: If you have a question about a step, feel free to ask.

Answer (score 1):

HINT:

This is a homogenous equation. If you have a non-trivial solution, you also have a solution with $\gcd(x,y,u,v)=1$. The important fact now is the following: if $a^2+b^2$ is divisible by $3$ then both $a$, $b$ are divisible by $3$. This can be proved by noticing that if $c$ is not divisible by $3$, then $c^2\equiv 1 \bmod{3}$. 
So assume you have a solution with $\gcd(x,y,u,v)=1$. Since $x^2 + y^2\equiv 0 \bmod{3}$, both $x$, $y$ are divisible by $3$, that is 
$x = 3 x_1$, $y = 3 y_1$. We get 
$$3(x_1^2 + y_1^2) = u^2 + v^2$$ and so both $u$, $v$ are divisible by $3$. But then we get $3 \mid \gcd(x,y,u,v)$, contradiction.

Answer (score 0):

The most obvious feature of this equation is that we have a sum of two squares which is a multiple of $3$. Let's think about that. If a sum of two squares $a^2+b^2$ is a multiple of $3$, then $a$ and $b$ each have to be a multiple of $3$ (to see this, just work modulo $3$). Here $x^2+y^2$ is a multiple of $3$, so:

$$x^2+y^2=3(u^2+v^2)$$
$$(3x')^2+(3y')^2=3(u^2+v^2)$$
$$3(x'^2+y'^2) = u^2+v^2$$

At this point you should start to sense that something fishy is going on, especially if you know about the method of [infinite descent](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Proof_by_infinite_descent).

If you want to solve this for yourself, you should stop reading this answer now, read about infinite descent if you haven't already, and take the above as a hint. Otherwise the full solution is below.

Let $A$ denote the set of all pairs $(x, y)$ such that $x^2+y^2$ is $3$ times a sum of two squares. Then the above calculation shows that if $(x, y)\in A$, we also have $(u, v)\in A$, and unless $(u, v)=(x,y)=(0,0)$, we must have $u^2+v^2<x^2+y^2$. So if there is some non-zero pair $(x, y)\in A$, then from it we can spawn an infinite descent of non-zero pairs $(u_i, v_i)$ which is strictly decreasing in euclidean norm. This is not possible, so therefore there is no non-zero pair $(x, y)$.

Comment: Thank you, I will ask further questions if I have trouble understanding any steps