# Are there infinitely many natural numbers that can be represented as $\frac{a^2+b^2}{c^2+d^2}$ with coprime $a$, $b$, $c$, $d$?

Tags: number-theory

> Are there infinitely many natural numbers that can be represented as the ratio
> $$
> \frac{a^2 + b^2}{c^2+d^2}
> $$
> where $a$, $b$, $c$, $d$ are coprime integers?

Is there a way to characterize all such numbers?

Comment: $c=d=1$, $a=2n-1, b=2n+1$

Comment: yes. Since both are primitively represented, the ratio, if an integer, is also primitive $x^2 + y^2$

Comment: Possibly all numbers that do not have a prime factor of the form 4K+3 at an odd power can be represented? And those are all the numbers? We might need to relax the coprime condition a bit

Comment: Oh, wait, do you mean pairwise coprime, or just all having GCD 1?

Comment: I meant pairwise  coprime but I realize my statement only asks for gcd=1. Think the answer might be indeed different depending on what you assume should be coprime. If it’s not pairwise then the answer below applies. If it s pairwise that restricts the solutions more.

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1127654/parametrization-of-solutions-of-diophantine-equation

Comment: $$p|n =\frac{a^2+b^2}{c^2+d^2} \Rightarrow a^2=-b^2 \pmod{p}$$ This implies that either $a=b=0 \pmod{p}$ (which is not possible if $gcd(a,b)=1$) or $-1$ is a quadratic residue modulo $p$ (giving $p=1 \pmod{4}$).

Answer (score 1):

Suppose the number $N > 1$ is such that it's prime decomposition has no term of the form $p^k$ with $k$ odd and $p \equiv 3 (4)$. Then it can be written as $\frac{a^2 + b^2}{1^2 + 1^2}$. This doesn't mean $a$ and $b$ are coprime though.

Now suppose the prime factorization of $N = p_1^{k_1} \cdots p_r^{k_r}$ with some being congruent to 3 modulo 4 and having odd powers. Then if we were to write $N = \frac{M}{O}$ then $M = p_1^{k_1 + \ell_1} \cdots p_r^{k_r + \ell_r} p_{r+1}^{\ell_{r+1}} \cdots p_s^{\ell_s}$ and $O = p_1^{\ell_1} \cdots p_r^{\ell_r} p_{r+1}^{\ell_{r+1}} \cdots p_s^{\ell_s}$ where we are free to choose the $\ell$'s among natural numbers as long as they are not all $0$. Then $M$ and $O$ are integers greater than $1$ that we want to write as sum of two squares each.

Suppose $p_j$ was such an offending prime. Then we know that $k_j$ was odd. But now we have it in $k_j + \ell_j$ and $\ell_j$ as it's powers in $M$ and $O$. If we use $\ell_j$ as odd, then $O$ can't be written as a sum of two squares. If we use $\ell_j$ as even, then $M$ can't be written as a sum of two squares because of the factor $p_j^{k_j+\ell_j}$ has an odd power.

So even by allowing the seemingly more general form of $\frac{a^2 + b^2}{c^2 + d^2}$ you have not gained any more natural numbers than can be written besides those that were already of the form $a^2 + b^2$.

Comment: For the coprime part I’m thinking that a number can be represented as the ratio if and only if it can be written as the sum of two coprime squares. So the answer would be all numbers that can be written as the sum of 2 coprime squares? Therefore the number needs to be a product of primes of the form 4K+1 at power at most 2?

Answer (score 0):

Excuse my late reaction, but I think the answer is already contained in the so called "Fermat Xmas theorem", which states that an odd prime $p$ is the sum of two (integral) squares iff $p \equiv 1$ mod $4$ (*). A consequence (due to Euler ?) is that a strictly positive integer is a sum of two squares iff in its prime decomposition, every factor   $p\equiv 3$ intervenes with an even exponent. Consider then an integer $N$ equal to a fraction whose numerator and denominator are both sums of two squares. The integrality of $N$ implies that each prime divisor of the denominator divides also the numerator, and with a lesser exponent. So that finally $N$ is already a sum of two squares.

(*) There exist quite a few different proofs of this Xmas theorem, but the record of brievity belongs to Don Zagier:« A one-sentence proof that every prime $p\equiv 1$(mod 4) is a sum of two squares », *The American Mathematical Monthly*, vol. 92, no 2,‎ 1990, p. 144.

Answer (score 0):

Observation: if n is a prime of the form of the form 4n + 1, not only is it the sum of two relatively prime squares, so is 2n. So make your denominator 1 + 1 and you're done. The problem is more fun if you exclude this trivial case.