# Check membership in set of bisquares

Tags: elementary-number-theory

A bisquare is a number which can be expressed as $p^2 + q^2$ where $p,q\in\mathbb{W} $. Given a number, how can you quickly tell if it is a bisquare or not? Is it even possible to do so without using the naive method?

Comment: http://math.stackexchange.com/a/153613/17976

Comment: @Mike I'm not too sure I understand the answers there. I'm a  bit of a newbie. If you'd tell me how to check, I'd be grateful. I should also close the question, right?

Comment: No need to close until you have an answer you're satisfied with.  I may or may not have time to give a full answer at the moment.

Comment: @Mike okay thanks.

Comment: @xrisk What does $\mathbb W$ mean?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The first step is to factor the number into primes.  The primes which matter for this are those which are one less than a multiple of $4$ ($3,7,11,19,$ etc.).  Now check the power of each of these primes.  If any of the powers is odd, the number cannot be represented as the sum of $2$ squares.

I'll need to add more later I think.

Comment: Question: Is this a quick method? (as we know the factorization is not an easy task)?

Comment: @Elaqqad I don't think there is a faster way to verify that a number can be represented as the sum of 2 squares.  There may however be certain cases that are easier to disprove.  For example, any number which is one less than a multiple of 4 cannot be represented as the sum of 2 squares and a number is divisible by 4 if the last 2 digits are divisible by 4.  So, for example, any number ending with the last 2 digits "19" can't be represented as the sum of 2 squares, no factorization needed.

Comment: @Mike, turns out there's a slight flaw in  your method. Consider - 9 you would qualify it as a bisquare - because $9 = 3^2$. But $9=0^2 + 3^2$ and 0 isn't a natural number :p But it turns out that this is what I'd originally wanted.

Comment: @xrisk To adjust the method to natural numbers only, just add the additional restriction that either the greatest power of $2$ dividing $n$ has odd exponent or there is at least one prime congruent to $1$ mod $4$ dividing $n$.

Comment: @xrisk Yes, that's why I thought I might have to add more later.  I think Erick Wong's method may provide a fix.

Comment: @Mike I don't need a fix. I later realized that I needed it for whole numbers and not natural numbers. I've edited the question too.

Comment: @ErickWong just looking through this thread and I couldn’t understand this  statement of yours "the greatest power of 2 dividing n has odd exponent” . Could you please explain how this applies to a number like 100 ?

Comment: @RishavKundu I said "or", not "and".  Which primes divide $100$?

Comment: @ErickWong Yes, I understood the other possible condition, but could not understand the first one. And 2 and 5 divide 100.

Comment: @RishavKundu Oh, you mean you couldn't understand the meaning.  The highest power of $2$ which divides $100$ is $2^2$.  The exponent is $2$, which is even, not odd.  Therefore $100$ does not satisfy the first clause of the "or" condition.

Comment: @RishavKundu However, your question was phrased very oddly.  If you understand the second clause of the "or", then you must know that $100$ satisfies the condition.  Wouldn't it make more sense to ask about $18$ or $36$?