# Diophantine equation $x^2+y^2=z^2+t^2$?

Tags: elementary-number-theory, diophantine-equations, sums-of-squares

I would like to find some source books or articles which discuss the Diophantine equation
$$
x^2+y^2=z^2+t^2,\qquad |y-z|=1
$$
for which $x,z$ are odd positive and $y,t$ are even positive integers.
Any brief explanation is also welcome and appreciated.

Thanks!

Comment: Rewrite it as $y^2 - z^2 = t^2 - x^2$ and factor both sides. I don't know why you expect such a specific question to be discussed in an article or a book, though.

Comment: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/153603/diophantine-equation-a2b2-c2d2/736164#736164    Use any formula. Substitute in the 2nd equation and then we solve the Pell equation. Its solution and then substitute in the formula.

Answer (score 2):

Is not so hard. $x^2-t^2=z^2-y^2 $, so $(x-t)*(x+t)=(z-y)*(z+y)$. Now suppose that$ z=y+1$.So $ (x-t)*(x+t)=y+z=2y+1$. Now it's so easy, you must to keep account by initial conditions.

Comment: Without loss of generality you can let $z=y+1$.

Answer (score 1):

What to do is just substitute your conditions on your equations. Since $x,z$ are odd and $y,t$ are even and $|y-z|=1$, then,

$$(2m-1)^2+(2u)^2 = (2u-1)^2+(2n)^2\tag1$$

Expanding, you can see that $2$nd powers of $u$ will cancel, so you'll only have a *linear* equation in $u$. Letting Walpha [do the work](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=Factor%5B%282m-1%29%5E2%2B%282u%29%5E2%20-%282u-1%29%5E2-%282n%29%5E2%5D), we get the condition,

$$u = -m^2+m+n^2$$

which makes $(1)$ true for any $m,n$.