# Solving an integer equation (equi-energy transition)

Tags: algebra-precalculus, diophantine-equations, integers

In chemistry, we came across an equation as follows:

$$\frac{Z_1^2}{n_1^2}-\frac{Z_1^2}{n_2^2}=\frac{Z_2^2}{n_3^2}-\frac{Z_2^2}{n_4^2}$$

We were supposed to assume that this implied that

$$\frac{Z_1}{Z_2}=\frac{n_1}{n_3}=\frac{n_2}{n_4}$$

Is there any mathematical reason why this holds true, or is it just a result that usually (but not always) holds true. All the $6$ variables mentioned are small positive integers (small would mean less than $100$ for sure).

Comment: Infinitely many solutions.  And not only these.  http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/153603/diophantine-equation-a2b2-c2d2/736164#736164

Comment: Not always. Take $Z_1=5,Z_2=1,n_1=48,n_2=36,n_3=16,n_4=9$.

Comment: @individ If the variables are smaller than 100 and greater than 1, surely there are not infinitely many solutions.