# Parametrization of pythagorean-like equation

Tags: number-theory, diophantine-equations

Is there any known complete parametrization of the Diophantine equation
$$
A^{2} + B^{2} = C^{2} + D^{2}
$$
where $A, B, C, D$ are (positive) rational numbers, or equivalently, integers?

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/153603/diophantine-equation-a2b2-c2d2/736164#736164

Answer (score 0):

Yes, there are. You can put
$$A=ms+nt\\B=nt-ms\\C=ms-nt\\D=mt+ns$$ where $m,n,s,t$ are arbitrary.

Comment: In your "soloution" it seems impossible for both B and C to be positive.

Comment: It should be $(A,B,C,D) = (p r + q s , q r - p s , p r - q s , p s + q r),$

Comment: @Peter Green: It is not "my solution" but a quite known parameterization in which I have  had an obvious lapse.

Comment: @Dietrich Burde.- Look please at my comment answering to Peter Green.