# Historical context of the quadruple $(x,y,z,t)$ where $x^2+y^2=z^2+t^2$

Tags: reference-request, diophantine-equations, math-history

Recently my study is related to an equation $x^2+y^2=z^2+t^2$. I have learned that Euler studied about numbers which can be represented as a sum of two squares in two different way. But I do not know if there is anyone who studied this equation before him.

So I would like to ask if there is a name and the historical context of the quadruple $(x,y,z,t)$ so that $x^2+y^2=z^2+t^2$.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it belongs to the [History of Science and Mathematics](https://hsm.stackexchange.com/) StackExchange site.

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/153603/diophantine-equation-a2b2-c2d2/736164#736164

Answer (score 2):

Any Pythagorean triple that has a hypotenuse that factors into $2$ distinct primes, to any power will have two sets of $(A,B)$ pairs where $A^2+B^2=C^2$. For example $65=5\times13$ so
$$33^2+56^2=65^2\quad
63^2+16^2=65^2\\
\implies 33^2+56^2=63^2+16^2
$$

There are infinite numbers of such triple pairs. There will be $2^{n-1}$ primitive triples for any given hypotenuse where $(n)$ is the number of its unique prime factors. Some will have more triples than this but the extras will be non-primitive.

The only historical context I can think of is the development of sums of squares representing integers whether they are squares or not. Some studies on the subject are [here](http://www.math.uchicago.edu/%7Emay/VIGRE/VIGRE2009/REUPapers/Wong.pdf) and [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fermat%27s_theorem_on_sums_of_two_squares).

Answer (score 0):

It is well known since longtime ago that the complete solutions of the equation $x^2+y^2=z^2+t^2$ is given by the following identity in four parameters $r,s,X,Y$

$$(rX+sY)^2+(rY-sX)^2=(rX-sY)^2+(rY+sX)^2$$