# Fermat's theorem on sums of two squares

Tags: number-theory, prime-numbers, sums-of-squares

There's [Fermat's theorem on sums of two squares](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fermat%27s_theorem_on_sums_of_two_squares).

As the prime numbers that are $1\bmod4$ can be divided into the sum of two squares, will the squared numbers be unique?

For example, $41=4^2+5^2$ and the squared numbers will be $4$ and $5$.

Comment: http://mathworld.wolfram.com/SumofSquaresFunction.html

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes,  if you don't take into account the order of the two numbers or $\pm$ sign in front of the numbers.

Answer (score 8):

Just to complement Pantelis' answer, the reason why they are unique can be easily seen from the proof using the Gaussian integers $\mathbb{Z}[i]$, which is a UFD.

Answer (score 4):

Primes of the form $p=4k+1\;$  have a unique decomposition as sum of squares $p=a^2+b^2$ with $0<a<b\;$, due to [Thue's Lemma](https://planetmath.org/ProofOfThuesLemma).

Further, primes of the form $p=4n+3$, never have a decomposition into $2$ squares, proven in various ways [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/163519/19341).

Comment: BTW: Unique solutions seem to be quite rare, as this unanswered question indicates: [Unique solutions for $n=\sum_{j=1}^{g(k)} a_j^k$](http://math.stackexchange.com/q/103432/19341)