# show the p is a sum of two squares - number theory

Tags: elementary-number-theory, prime-numbers, sums-of-squares

If $p$ is a the sum of two squares are integers $a$ and $b$ s.t. $p=a^2 + b^2$ then $p=1$ mod $4$. 
I need help proving that.

Comment: see also [Sum of two squares $n = a^2 + b^2$](http://math.stackexchange.com/q/246434/19341)

Comment: This isn't actually true...it could be $p \equiv 0 \pmod 4$.  Do you mean to assume that $p$ is prime?

Comment: Related : http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/122048/1-is-a-quadratic-residue-modulo-p-if-and-only-if-p-equiv-1-pmod4

Answer (score 2):

Hints:

Take $\;\Bbb Z/4\Bbb Z=\{0,1,2,3\}\pmod 4\;$ and observe what's the general form of its squares.

Now take the expression $\;a^2+b^2\pmod 4\;$ . Taking into account the first point and the fact that $\;p\;$ is a prime, what can you deduce?