# prove that the equation $4x^2 + y^2 = 4f^2 + 1$ has a unique solution y = 1 and x = $\sqrt{f^2} $ if $4f^2 + 1$ is prime.

Tags: prime-numbers

prove that the equation $4x^2 + y^2 = 4f^2 + 1$ has a unique solution y = 1 and x = $\sqrt{f} $ if $4f^2 + 1$ is prime. I have no ideas, maybe it's impossible or the statement is false. I found proof thah equation $x^2 + y^2 = p$ has at least 1 solution, but nothing about unique

Comment: For which range of primes have you verified this numerically (= by brute force)? Saying that you have no ideas rings a bit hollow.

Comment: true for n up to 10000

Comment: Why hide that piece of information into a comment as opposed to in the question body where everybody can see it? Also, is the solution to be $x=f$ or $x=\sqrt f$ (when the equation should be $x^2+y^2=4f+1$ rather than $x^2+y^2=4f^2+1$)?

Comment: It was [a duplicate](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/169020).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Any prime p equal to 1 modulo 4 has a unique presentation p = a^2 + b^2, up to the order of the summands. See here: https://proofwiki.org/wiki/Fermat%27s_Two_Squares_Theorem

Comment: as far as I understand this theorem implites that the solution is unique? In the other interpretations of this theoreme they mention only about the existence of solutions, not about unique

Comment: Yes, the solution is unique for every prime.

Comment: Thanks! I havent even heard about Fermat's Two Squares Theorem/Uniqueness Lemma

Comment: It was [a duplicate](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/169020). In such a predictable case, better look for an older post and link to it, than edit one more answer.